# Interesting pointer behaviour with scanf and while loop

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop, scanf

I am a web developer and studying C in my spare time.
I couldn't think of a clear explanation to the case below.

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int *ptr = arr;

char in1[1];
char forward;
char back;

printf("Start from Adress: %p |||| Value: %d\n", ptr, *ptr);
forward = 0;
back = 1;

while( back<10 ){
    back++;
    ptr++;
    printf("walked forward..\n----\nAdress: %p |||| Value: %d\n ", ptr, *ptr);
}
```

Works as expected and gives results,

> Adress: 0x7fff57954220 |||| Value: 1
>
> Adress: 0x7fff57954224 |||| Value: 2
>
> Adress: 0x7fff57954228 |||| Value: 3

and so on..

but the one below gives strange results,

```
while( (!forward && back) || (forward && !back) ){  
    scanf("%s", in1);
    forward = strncmp(in1,"f",1);
    back = strncmp(in1,"b",1);

    if(!forward){
    ptr++;
    printf("walked forward..\n----\nAdress: %p |||| Value: %d\n ", ptr,      *ptr);
    }
    else if(!back){
    ptr--;
    printf("walked backwards..\n----\nAdress: %p |||| Value: %d\n ",   ptr, *ptr);
    }
}
```

increment 3 steps:

> Adress: 0x7fff572da204 |||| Value: 1711277311
>
> Adress: 0x7fff572da204 |||| Value: 1711277311
>
> Adress: 0x7fff572da204 |||| Value: 1711277311

decrement 3 steps:

> Adress: 0x7fff577c91fc |||| Value: 16809983
>
> Adress: 0x7fff577c90fc |||| Value: 512
>
> Adress: 0x7fff577c8ffc |||| Value: 0

Why is this? How does scanf() effect pointer behaviour or memory organisation?

Comment: `scanf` doesn't affect pointer behavior, it's just a function

Comment: What **is** happening is that you use access memory outside the bounds of your buffer with the pointer. And what you get is the result of undefined behavior. And as the name implies, anything can happen.

Comment: `char in1[1];` does not have any room for an input string apart from a single `'\0'` terminator. And seeing as `scanf("%s", in1);` will not accept the empty string as an input, you are **guaranteed** to overflow the string.

Comment: One thing that `scanf` does is append a null-terminating character, and your buffer is 1-character wide.

Comment: `scanf` is writing multiple bytes to a one-byte array `in1[1]`. The result is undefined behavior. Change it to `in1[256]`, and don't type more than 255 characters.

Comment: @user3386109 ... including the new-line entered by pressing the  ... well ... enter-key.

Comment: @alk `scanf` does not store the `enter` key - that's `fgets`.

Comment: phew .. yes sure, temp brian-laps again .. quiting for the day. @WeatherVane

Comment: Thank you. I think i was not aware of a null terminator. I did in1[1] because i thought i would use "f" and "b" as controllers only. But apparently they have terminators.

Comment: @AliSomay C does not have a formal `string` type. It is an array of `char` with a `'\0'` terminator. Note that you can add a max length qualifier to the `scanf` format, for example `scanf("%9s", in1);` assuming that you have `char in1[10];`